# how to avoid reload of one jsp page in another jsp page

Tags: jsp

I have included a jsp page in another jsp page. I want my child jsp page to be not reload when  I reload my parent jsp page . Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Ajax/jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/